# Minimal Haskell OpenGL Example causes OpenGL Error

Tags: haskell, opengl, glut

I was toying with an OpenGL example and ran into a problem.  I minimized it to one of the [mainstream Haskell/OpenGL examples](https://wiki.haskell.org/OpenGLTutorial1).  This is with Windows 10, Haskell Platform (32-bit 8.0.2-a.  Almost positive it's the -a variant).

```
import Graphics.UI.GLUT

main :: IO ()
main = do
  (_progName, _args) <- getArgsAndInitialize
  _window <- createWindow "Hello World"
  displayCallback $= display
  mainLoop

display = do
  let color3f r g b = color $ Color3 r g (b :: GLfloat)
      vertex3f x y z = vertex $ Vertex3 x y (z :: GLfloat)
  clear [ColorBuffer]
  renderPrimitive Points $ do
    -- color3f 1 0 0
    -- vertex3f 0 0 0
    return ()
  -- << error on glEnd() of renderPrimtive >>

  flush
  reportErrors
```

Facts:

- I've tried this with the default `glut32.dll` that comes with the Haskell Platform (GHC 8.0.2) and I also tried `freeglut`.  Using gDEBugger, I was able to determine that the `glEnd` command reports the error first (called by `renderPrimtive`).  Even with no body (vertices or color changes), the render issues some command that makes OpenGL unhappy (, or the empty command generates a different error).
- I tried this with other primitives too `Lines` and even the example program from the link above (uses `Quads`).
- The primitives actually render correctly on my screen even with the error.  (But I desire error checking for my own screw ups, so this false positive is bad.)

*Does anyone have an idea how to go about debugging this?* Thanks!

Comment: I would begin by testing the equivalent C program to determine if the issue is with the Haskell bindings. Also note that GLUT (provided by `glut32.dll` or `freeglut.dll`) and OpenGL (provided by `glu32.dll` and `opengl32.dll`) are different libraries (although the latter is a dependency of the former).

Comment: Yep, I was aware that glut wraps the other DLLs. I was hoping it was something obvious, e.g.  "Yes, known bug in the Haskell OGL bindings...." Surely, a similar "hello world" example gets tested by the bindings library. I guess I have to write the C program. :(

Comment: I don't think this is a Haskell-specific problem. I vaguely recall that some GLUT implementations would cause an OpenGL error before the first application-issued OpenGL call (I think it was something related to trying to check extensions without a context).  To see if that's the problem, call `glGetError()` as soon as you have a context (which occurs in GLUT when the window opens).  The GL error flag persists across calls until `glGetError` is called, so you may indeed be getting a stale error.

Comment: Hmm. Still in Haskell. There are no errors after context creation, but I did determine that the error is only raised once (on the first `glEnd()`. Successive frames don't create errors. I'll try C.